# Upward Navigation Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make it so when I click on the toggle button, all the content (the general, trending, your posts) go up and out of the page with a transition, and the only remaining thing on the page would be the toggle button. So, when the toggle button is clicked, the content should go up and have absolutely no display, but the toggle button should still be visible on the screen, in case the user wants to bring back the "general, trending, your posts" from their no display. Thank you very much, answers are appreciated. Here is my code:

```js
const navigation = document.querySelector('.navigation');
document.querySelector('.toggle').onclick = function() {
  this.classList.toggle('active');
  navigation.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
hr.two {
  height: 5px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, orange, blue, green, yellow, purple, red);
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-left: -8px;
  width: 1436px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rajdhani:wght@600&display=swap');
.toggle {
  position: fixed;
  left: 1210px;
  top: 145px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 30px;
  background: orange;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 5px solid #E0E0E0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}

.toggle::before {
  content: '\f077';
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
}

.toggle.active::before {
  content: '\f078';
}

.container .navigation {
  position: relative;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  background: #E0E0E0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.container .navigation a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.container .navigation.active {
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  transition: 5s;
}
```

```html
<hr class="two" style="margin-top:-235px">

<div class="navigation">
  <div class="container" style="position:fixed; margin-top:-7px">
    <a href="home.php" style="margin-left:1040px; text-decoration:none; color:orange; font-size:24px; border-top:8px solid blue; font-family:Verdana; margin-top:-1px; position:fixed">General</a>
    <a href="trending.php" style="margin-left:1153px; text-decoration:none; color:orange; font-size:24px; font-family:Verdana; margin-top:7px; position:fixed">Trending</a>
    <a href="yourposts.php" style="margin-left:1278px; text-decoration:none; color:orange; font-size:24px; font-family:Verdana; position:fixed; margin-top:8px">Your Posts</a>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="toggle"></div>
```

Comment: Hello, before tackling the actual question, I want to say that your css is pretty bad imo. You use fixed positioning and fixed negative margins and stuff like that which makes the website everything but responsive (it doesn't even show up in the code snippet)

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is what you are looking for:

```js
document.getElementById("toggleBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector("nav").classList.toggle("hidden");
});
```

```css
nav {
  transition: all 0.5s;
  height: 100%;
}

nav.hidden {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  height: 0%;
}

nav {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  display: flex;
}

.navlink {
  display: block;
  margin: 1.5em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border: solid blue 2pt;
  padding: 1em 3em;
}
```

```html
<hr />
<nav>
  <a class="navlink" href="home.php">General</a>
  <a class="navlink" href="trending.php">Trending</a>
  <a class="navlink" href="yourposts.php">Your Posts</a>
</nav>
<button id="toggleBtn">Toggle</button>
```

The way I am doing this is by translating the nav on the Y axis by -100%, which makes it invisible (if on the top of the page). I also tried to kinda imitate your layout, but using much simpler and more responsive CSS.

Comment: The only thing is that the button that is beneath doesn't go up. You can try setting `height:0px;` to `nav.hidden` but there will be no smooth transition.